# Altium rules for autoconnecting a polygon to LQFP like pins

Tags: altium, polygon

The image shows that the GND pins are not connected to pins near pads with no similar net around them. What I am looking for is defining or changing rules so that Altium would be able to do so on repouring polygons.

What should I do?

[image: Described Image]

Comment: Decrease trace/pad to polygon clearance, or add fanouts.

Comment: @TimWilliams How exactly should I add fanout control? I mean how to manage the rule parameters? changing polygon clearance made it get close to all other pins also.

Answer (score 0):

What is your polygon connect style set for for SMD pads? If you have thermal relief (**Relief Connect**), that is usually the reason for this sort of non-connection.

[image: Altium polygon connect style rule dialog in DRC]

Changing it to **Direct Connect** will often fix this sort of problem, but you may not want to do this for your entire board. In that case, you may have to create another rule which selects the specific component this should apply to. Alternately, you could create a room which applies a direct connection style only within its boundaries (again, using a design rule).

A quick "hack" is to manually draw tracks to connect these pads. For some of my boards where I only have this problem with one or two components, that is often an acceptable solution.

Comment: Well, My problem is solved by a mixture of what you said and Tim Williams comment